# How do I find the count of a substring in a string when substring and string both are lists?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, loops

I'm trying to count the words of one list (X) that appears in another list (Y). The list I'm iterating over has multiple words in a single string.

Example:

```
X = ['abc def ghi klm', 'xyz bef mno', 'jkl mno pqr abc', 'xyz mno def']

Y = ['def', 'xyz', 'abc', 'tuv']
```

OUTPUT should be something like :

Count of Y items:

```
def = 2
xyz = 2
abc = 2
```

What I tried:

```
for obj in X:
    for item in Y:
        if obj in item:
            freq = obj.count(item)
            print (freq)
```

I also tried list comprehension but I believe that's not the case for it.

Comment: Please, show how you have tried to solve this.

Comment: I am voting this to close this as off topic

Comment: SO is not a code writing service

Comment: `def` occurs twice . Why it should be `def = 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get exactly what you need (shouldn't `def = 2` in your example?), but I think this might be close to what you need:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

counts = defaultdict(int)
for x, y in product(X, Y):
    if y in x:
        counts[y] += 1
```

You can check the output by running:

```
for k, v in counts.items():
    print('{} = {}'.format(k, v))
```

which prints:

```
def = 2
abc = 2
xyz = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Short *one-line* solution using built-in `sum()` function:

```
x = ['abc def ghi klm', 'xyz bef mno', 'jkl mno pqr abc', 'xyz mno def']
y = ['def', 'xyz', 'abc', 'tuv']
result = {i: sum(w.count(i) for w in x) for i in y}

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'def': 2, 'xyz': 2, 'tuv': 0, 'abc': 2}
```

**----------**

Or with `collections.Counter` object:

```
import collections
x = ['abc def ghi klm', 'xyz bef mno', 'jkl mno pqr abc', 'xyz mno def']
y = ['def', 'xyz', 'abc', 'tuv']

c = collections.Counter(' '.join(x).split())
result = {i: c[i] for i in y if i in c}

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'abc': 2, 'def': 2, 'xyz': 2}
```

Comment: The `sum()` oneliner won't work, because there are multiple words in a single string in X. so it would check 'abc def ghi klm' as a single element

Comment: @Vinny, wrong, `i in w` will check if for ex. `def` occurs in `abc def ghi klm`. You suspicion may be reasonable only if single `x` item contains repeated `y` items. I don't see such input and such condition. So it'll work (untill the OP declared a new conditions)

Comment: @Vinny, Besides, I've extended my `sum` approach for potential case "if single `x` item contains repeated `y` items". It will definitely work

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is iterarting over the X list, manipulate your string to split on spaces (so you get each word separated) and then using Counter class to create a dict that counts occurences only of the items exists in Y

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for word in X:
        words = word.split(' ')
        words = [w for w in words if w in Y]
        c.update(words)

>>> c
Counter({'xyz': 3, 'abc': 3, 'def': 3, 'tuv': 1})
```